# Adjusting pdf file content in C++

Tags: c++, pdf

I have a pdf file which, when I open in notepad++, needs a small adjustments.
If I do it manually, it works ok.
I want to do it in a small c++ program.
What I try to do is read as binary stream, and adjust the content on the run.
example:

```
std::ofstream outputStream(output,std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::binary);
std::ifstream inputStream( input, std::ofstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
for(std::string stringInput; getline(inputStream,stringInput); )
{
    if (stringInput.find("abc") != std::string::npos && stringInput.find("#1") != std::string::npos)
      stringInput.replace(....);
outputStream << stringInput << endl;
stringInput.clear()
}
```

However, It never matches. and its there. dont know why.
Am I doing something wrong about binary files / io methods?
is it the correct way?
When I tried to read as text file, It didnt write newlines and it couldnt handle anything other than chars. Im not sure why tough

Comment: Also, hacking your way into the PDF format to try and replace/insert stuff is likely to eventually break and is definitely not the right way to proceed. Don't rely on it working.

Comment: What kind of text are you trying to replace that way? Hopefully not content stream strings? They in general may use a completely custom encoding, so they may look like complete gibberish to you.

Comment: Well, no. I want to replace a minor part which is encoded regulary. I can see it in notepad++ as regular text. if i fix it "by hand" with notepad it works fine. so I just want to apply an automatic fix.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `getline` on a file that doesn't consist of lines. For one thing, it borks the line endings, which renders the result incomprehensible.

Comment: So how should I both mix a string C++ object with a for loop in C+?

Comment: You shouldn't. You're trying to manipulate binary data and should not pretend that it's a text string.

Comment: I want to edit a part which is text part. Its not the binary part. I have to read as binary just in order for the copy to work.

Comment: That's correct. You have to read it in, analyze it, and write it out as binary.

Comment: Well, the only issue I have is that newline is get written to the text file. Im tried both getline() and >> operator, combined with endl for writing. why isnt it writing newlines?

Comment: Don't write newlines specifically. Just treat newline the same as any other character you don't match -- pass it through unmolested.

Comment: But how do i read unformatted from ifstream to a std::string?

Comment: Don't use a `std::string`. Just [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) raw binary data. (Then use [gcount](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) to know how many bytes you read.)

Comment: Is that the only way? Then Im limited to strchr / looping char by char and have nothing ofthe string library. frustrating.

Comment: You can use [memchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memchr/). You could use `std::string` to hold binary data, and use [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) -- C++ strings can hold embedded zero bytes and line endings -- but it's tricky to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

Get a PDF library that does all the complicated stuff for you.

The PDF file format is so complex that you cannot implement it correctly in one year or less. Others have done lots of good work in that direction, so you should rather trust *them*.

Look for a PDF library that reads a PDF file as a list of tokens. Your code should then look like this:

```
PdfInputStream in("input.pdf");
PdfOutputStream out("out.pdf");
PdfToken token;

while (in >> token) {
  if (token.isText()) {
    token.replaceText("abc", "#1");
  }
  out << token;
}
```

Comment: `token.replaceText("abc", "#1")` - don't count on that being possible in general. Content stream strings may look like binary trash. And in case of partially embedded fonts your replacement may not print as desired.

Comment: Oh, yeah, it's a feature called “subset encoding”, but most of these font should have a translation table (for copy and paste), so it might work in some cases, and the library should handle it. The change in string width is another issue, indeed. But by using this method at least the byte offsets in the file will be correct.

Comment: *it might work in some cases, and the library should handle it* - Well, there are many libraries out there that **don't** handle that case. After all, for replacing with characters which are not yet embedded, the embedded font subset would have to be changed; many libraries don't deem the effort worthwhile.